# How to count the amount of values grouped by some column?

Tags: postgresql, view, group-by

I need to create a `view` based on data from another table and grouped by some column value. Here is a source table:

```
CREATE TABLE source
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 6, 1000 ),
    ( 6, 2000 ),
    ( 7, 5000 ),
    ( 7, 6000 )
  ) AS t(client_id, score);
```

and the desired `view` is:

```
 client_id | score
----+---------+---
 6         | 3000 
 7         | 11000
```

As far as I know, it's convenient to use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) in this case. But what way will be most effective for grouping by `client_id` field?

Thank you.

Comment: That is a simple `group by` query. No window functions required

Comment: What do you mean by 'convenient to use window functions in this case'? IMO, you don't need window functions for this. All you need is a simple group by query - select client_id, sum(score) from table group by client_id. You can add an order by if you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need a view for something this simple. But this is what it would look like

```
CREATE VIEW desired_view
AS
  SELECT client_id, sum(score)
  FROM source
  GROUP BY client_id;
```

Output

```
 client_id |  sum  
-----------+-------
         6 |  3000
         7 | 11000
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I was a little embarrassed by the scope of the window functions. Thanks for the explanation and simple solution to the problem.